# Get the checked state of a switch inside a ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have a ListView with a custom adapter. Inside the adapter I add a switch to a row. Now I created this code inside the Adapter code:

```
SettingSwitch.CheckedChange += (s, b) =>
{
    bool isChecked = SettingSwitch.Checked;


    SettingDb setting = new SettingDb()
    {
        Name = SettingName.Text,
        Value = isChecked.ToString()
    };

    MainActivity.db.UpdateTableSettings(setting);
};
```

But it turns out that `SettingSwitch.Checked` always returns false!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a collection to store the check status of the switch,and then load the collection when it is loaded in getView,like this get the correct state:

```
class YourAdapter : BaseAdapter,CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private Dictionary<int, bool> checkDictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
    int[] item;  //raplace your own data
    public MyAdapter(int[] value) //raplace your own data
    {
        item = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
        {
            checkDictionary.Add(i,false);
        }
    }

     public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout6, null);
            }

            Switch sSwitch = convertView.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SettingSwitch);
            sSwitch.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            sSwitch.Checked = checkDictionary[position];
            sSwitch.Tag = position;
            sSwitch.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            return convertView;

        }
    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {
            var position = buttonView.Tag;

            //here store the correct state and do something you want
            checkDictionary[(int) position] = isChecked;

        }
 }
```